# Autodesk Forge API V1 shutdown? or is it?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-viewer

view and data API (V1) stopped working yesterday. Today it works. Is it going to work tomorrow?

We are using autodesk viewer in our product. We missed the memo on V1 API going down on August 10th. So yesterday our app went down. We hacked something together to get a basic version running but because of the V2 model derivative format changes, not everything works. Today V1 APIs work again... Is there a second extension to V1 availability? I cannot find any info on this on Forge website.

Comment: We've been announcing that shutdown months ahead... the best place for you to keep up to date would be the Forge blog: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

Yes, View & Data v1 is deprecated and you should migrate to v2. We turn it back on due to the unexpected number of developers that still use it.

This [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-giving-error-403-unauthorized) explains it, please follow the steps to migrate your app.

Comment: I've seen that blog post. Are there announcements / mailing lists I could subscribe to to avoid missing such important blog posts in the future?

Is this extension of V1 official? We would like to know how much buffer time we have. We are in middle of migration, but it will take at least a week to make our model work with the new API data model.

If you see "unexpected number of developers", maybe you should provision it better and have more realistic expectations.

Comment: you should have received a newsletter on the email registered on Developer Portal. We'll repeat the announcements on the blog and newsletter, thanks for the feedback.